# Microchip 48LM01 memory secure read operation CRC and STM32 hardware CRC

Tags: stm32, microchip, non-volatile-memory, crc

I'm trying to use STM32 hardware CRC calculation mechanism to get CRC value from this data (3 byte address and 128 bytes of data):

```
// address
0x00 0x00 0x00

// data read
0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x0a 0x0b 0x0c 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f 
0x10 0x11 0x12 0x13 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x17 0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x1d 0x1e 0x1f 
0x20 0x21 0x22 0x23 0x24 0x25 0x26 0x27 0x28 0x29 0x2a 0x2b 0x2c 0x2d 0x2e 0x2f 
0x30 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x36 0x37 0x38 0x39 0x3a 0x3b 0x3c 0x3d 0x3e 0x3f 
0x40 0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44 0x45 0x46 0x47 0x48 0x49 0x4a 0x4b 0x4c 0x4d 0x4e 0x4f 
0x50 0x51 0x52 0x53 0x54 0x55 0x56 0x57 0x58 0x59 0x5a 0x5b 0x5c 0x5d 0x5e 0x5f 
0x60 0x61 0x62 0x63 0x64 0x65 0x66 0x67 0x68 0x69 0x6a 0x6b 0x6c 0x6d 0x6e 0x6f 
0x70 0x71 0x72 0x73 0x74 0x75 0x76 0x77 0x78 0x79 0x7a 0x7b 0x7c 0x7d 0x7e 0x7f
```

When I send `SECURE READ` opcode, and 0x000000 address to 48LM01 chip it responds with 128 bytes (above) and CRC value: `0x9D3D`.

Datasheet says, that this chip uses x^16+x^12+x^5+1 polynomial and initial value is 0xFFFF.
This is my (wrong?) CRC configuration in STM32CubeIDE:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
#define TEST_DATA_LEN 128
#define EERAM_ADDRESS_BYTES 3

typedef struct {
    uint8_t address[EERAM_ADDRESS_BYTES];
    uint8_t data[TEST_DATA_LEN];
    uint8_t crc[2];
} buffer_t;

// (...)

buffer_t buffer;
buffer.address[0] = 0;
buffer.address[1] = 0;
buffer.address[2] = 0;

// fill buffer with test data from 0 to 127
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < TEST_DATA_LEN; i++)
{
    buffer.data[i] = i;
}

uint32_t computed_crc = HAL_CRC_Calculate(pCrc, (uint8_t*)(&buffer.address), TEST_DATA_LEN + EERAM_ADDRESS_BYTES);

// memory contains data from 0 to 127 starting from 0 address
// my function reads it correctly and reads also 2 bytes of CRC
buffer_t readBuffer;
EERAM_SecureRead(0, &readBuffer.data);

// readBuffer at this point contains correct data and 0x9D3D CRC
```

After many tries (with inverted byte order, inverted data/address positions) **I can't get 0x9D3D CRC**.

I have found some page ([link to crccalc.com](https://crccalc.com/?crc=000000000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f303132333435363738393a3b3c3d3e3f404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f505152535455565758595a5b5c5d5e5f606162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b7c7d7e7f&method=crc16&datatype=hex&outtype=hex)) with many CRC type calculations, but none of them returns 0x9D3D.

**What is wrong with my CRC calculation?**

Comment: You probably need to read and understand the HAL_CRC_Calc source.

Comment: It just puts bytes into CRC data register, hardware replaces it with computed current CRC value.

Comment: Are you sure the address and data are contiguous in memory? Have you checked that there is no dummy memory alignment bytes between address and data in the struct?

Comment: Which specific STM32 model is this? Depending on the model they have wildly different CRC calculation module. Are you sure it can even calculate a byte-wise CRC that is not a multiple of 4 bytes? All the parameters (initial state, which bit of which byte is sent first, final xor) need to match or the two results will not match.

Comment: @Justme Data address is 0, memory is in 128 byte pages. Regarding memory alignment - datasheet says about 128 byte alignment if I understand correctly - 0, 128, 256... addresses should work (my english is not perfect). I'm sending data like this: 3 bytes of address (0,0,0) and I read 130bytes (128 data and 2 CRC).

Comment: @Justme it is STM32G474RE. I have looked at HAL function. There is 4 byte at once loading, and if there is some remainder (1-3bytes) it is being loaded one by one to CRC.DR (data register).

Comment: @Justme In the SPI transmission first byte is being sent first, with MSbit first.

Comment: I did not mean the organization or SPI direction of the memory chip. I meant the struct in STM32 memory. Check if it has padding, and if it does, you need to either calculate CRC differently or pack the struct. And make sure STM32 CRC calculates same bits first from bytes and same bytes first as the memory chip.

Comment: @Justme Oh, I see. I'll just try with single array `uint8_t buffer[131]` and try put data there and calculate CRC on STM32, instead of using struct.

Comment: @Justme I tried to feed HAL CRC library with 131 byte array. Same result. I switched to LL (LowLevel) driver instead of HAL. I feed CRC peripherial with 131 bytes in order 0,0,0, 0,1,2...127. Same results :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong is that the chip datasheet clearly mentions that only the valid bits of the address are used for CRC calculations.

As the 48LM01 uses 17 address bits, the upper 7 bits of the first address byte are not used in the CRC calculations, and thus it is incorrect to calculate the CRC by using the whole byte.

Comment: I saw that, but I don't understand how can I calculate CRC for 17 bits not taking 7 bits into account. Shall I truncate polynomial or initial value to 1 bit at the first stage of calculation?

Comment: Well the hardware CRC is not that suitable for data that is not byte-aligned. You need to do various tricks to pull it off, like initializing the CRC value to not 0xFFFF, but to something depending on if the first address bit is 0 or 1. Try calculating it in software first to see that you are able to calculate it, then control the hardware CRC to perform the same.

Comment: I'll just use diffrent kind of memory. Weird Microchip products take too much of my time. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please note that you don't have to use the CRC with this memory either if you don't want to.

Comment: I realize that. Just wanted it do work as it should. Actually I have to add some CRC to my data anyway, because "secure" operations are only "secure" in terms of data transmission over SPI. I guess that data corruption in this fancy memory kind is waaay more probable than problems with SPI.